# Is there a way to get Microsoft Flow failure notification in MS Teams?

Tags: notifications, alert, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I need to get an alert in MS Teams channel whenever there is a failure in my flow.Is this possible?

Comment: Could you please check if this helps: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/error-handling/

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Thanks for the quick response.I was able to get an email notification when failures occurs,but I am really looking for an alert in MS Teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is MS Teams connector available where you can integrate MS Flows.Once integrated,you can add action in flow to get messages in teams specific channel whenever there is a failure in the flow.

Thanks